# Proper setup for DefaultEventExecutorGroup in Netty 4.0

Tags: netty

I am misunderstanding either the role or the setup for the DefaultEventExecutorGroup.

I have a handler:

**HandlerClass:**

```
public RequestEventHandler extends LongDelayThreadCapable

private final static int SLEEP_IN_SECONDS = 10;

public RequestEventHandler()
{
    super(ConfigurationRequestEventHandler.supportedEvent);
}

@Override
public void userEventTriggered(final ConfigurationRequestEvent event) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ " + new Date());

    // Simulate a long query to a legacy JDBC connection
    Thread.sleep(ConfigurationRequestEventHandler.SLEEP_IN_SECONDS * 1000);

    System.out.println("CONFIGURATION ANSWER @ " + new Date());
}
```

which I added to the pipeline like so:

**Pipeline addition:**

```
public SetupTest(final List<ChannelHandler> channelHandlers)
{
    super();
    handlers = channelHandlers;
    executorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(Constants.EXECUTOR_THREADS);
}

public void initChannel(final ChannelPipeline pipeline) throws Exception
{
    Assert.notNull(pipeline, "Pipeline must not be null");

    if (handlers != null)
    {
        for (final ChannelHandler h : handlers)
        {
            if (h instanceof LongDelayThreadCapable)
            {
                pipeline.addLast(executorGroup, h.getClass().getSimpleName(), h);
            }
            else
            {
                pipeline.addLast(h);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My expectation is that if three events were to come in rapid succession that the events would be handled asynchronously and subsequently the output of the process would be:

```
run
CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ [date]
CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ [date]
CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ [date]
CONFIGURATION ANSWER
CONFIGURATION ANSWER
CONFIGURATION ANSWER
```

but instead the output indicates serial processing:

```
run
CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ [date]
CONFIGURATION ANSWER
CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ [date]
CONFIGURATION ANSWER
CONFIGURATION REQUEST @ [date]
CONFIGURATION ANSWER
```

I have seen a number of posts where there is discussion and statements are made that Netty 4.0 will always use a single thread. This seems contradictory to the idea of this EventGroup.

Is it possible to have multiple long queries going at the same time and if so, how do we wire pieces together to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will use the same EventExecutor for the same Channel as otherwise you may would get out of order processing of your handler which is not what you want for TCP. If you really want to do this just use your own Executor in your handler and dispatch stuff manually.

Comment: So the multiple threads allocated in the DefaultEventExecutorGroup really speak to how many rapid succession calls could come in from multiple channels. So if 10 channels had similar requests come in then they would be processed asynchronously.  But when the events all happen in the same channel, they are processed serially in order to maintain proper order.  Yes?